# Blazor Server - Insert CustomerID when inserting a Project to another table

Tags: c#, sql, insert, blazor

My project has a few tiers here.  Customer -> Project

The Project Table has a value for the CustomerID.
I'm getting a list of CustomerNames using my CustomersModel.

Simple example of what I'm trying to do here.  Choose a customer from a list and then type in a new Project Name and submit that to a table.  Binding the CustomerID causes the "Chose a Customer" option to not show up in the select drop down.  If I put CustomerName is the bound value it will show as the placeholder for the drop down.

But I need to pass the CustomerID to the Projects Table with the new Project Name.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

### --

Component Code

```
                                        <EditForm Model="@newProject" OnValidSubmit="@InsertLocation">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label class="form-label">Customer Name</label>
                                <InputSelect class="form-control" id="CustomerName" @bind-Value="newProject.CustomerID">
                                @if (customer is null)
                                        {

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <option selected disabled value="-1"> Choose a Customer</option>
                                        @foreach (var customer in customers)
                                            {
                                            <option>@customer.CustomerName</option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                </InputSelect>
                                @*<ValidationMessage For="(() => newProject.CustomerID)" />*@
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label class="form-label">Location Name</label>
                                <InputText class="form-control" id="ProjectName" @bind-Value="newProject.ProjectName" placeholder="Location Name" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="(() => newProject.ProjectName)" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

@code from the component

```
    private ProjectsViewModel newProject = new ProjectsViewModel();
    private async Task InsertLocation()
{

    //assign the new project data to the project model in the back end
    ProjectsModel project = new ProjectsModel
    {
        //TODO: make these match what is in the model and update insert query
        ProjectName = newProject.ProjectName,
        CustomerID = newProject.CustomerID

    };

    await projectsData.InsertLocation(project); //send data to db
    newProject = new ProjectsViewModel();
    projects = await projectsData.ReadProjects();
    OpenAddLocationModal = false;

}
```

And finally sending to the stored procedure from the projectData file.

```
        public async Task InsertLocation(IProjectsModel project)
    {
        var p = new
        {
            project.CustomerID,
            project.ProjectName
        };
        await _db.SaveData("dbo.spProject_Create", p, "DefaultConnection");
    }
```

SQL Procedure

```
@ProjectName nvarchar(255),
@CustomerID int

as

begin
insert into dbo.Projects(CustomerID, ProjectName)
values (@CustomerID, @ProjectName);
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `<option>@customer.CustomerName</option>` - where's the value?

Comment: There is a customer table and a project table.  In short every customer has man projects.  The value for CustomerName is in the customer table. Each Customer has in ID number, I need that ID number to pass to the projects table.  This is how it pull the right project for each customer.  The value comes through the customer model.

Comment: What I'm saying is, the `<option` doesn't contain a `value=`, so how will Blazor know what value to provide to `newProject.CustomerId`?

Comment: Alright you made me think here.  I did <option value="@customer.CustomerID">@customer.CustomerName</option>  I had it write to the console and it gives me the correct CustomerID, but submitting to the database still isn't happening when submitting a new project.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `await db.SaveData` line and inspect the values of `p`

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: Aye carumba! Learning to use the debugger effectively will probably be the most important thing you ever do in c#. As a mini tutorial, click on the line I said, press F9 so it goes red (that's a breakpoint) and run the app. Do the save click and the IDE will stop with a yellow bar on the breakpoint. Now you can give variables with your mouse or look in the Locals/Autos windows to see their values and you can press F10 to run the program a step at a time and work out where it went wrong. Definitely check out some YouTube tutorials out using the debugger though

Comment: If the `p` has the correct values then there is a problem in the Save method. If there seems no problem in Save, check you're looking in the correct db when you assert there are no items

Comment: I just got breakpoint working right before your reply.  The way I used here was just to have it remove the breakpoint when hit.  I tested this on another procedure I know works.   That said, it's not hitting the breakpoint for await _db.SaveData on this one.  So my guess is nothing is getting passed to it.  Further the validation does not seem to be working in my edit form.  I'm going to poke at this for awhile and I will absolutely hit some youtube about break points.  And now go try the way you suggested.

Comment: If the breakpoint on Save doesn't hit then the code is never reaching to there.. maybe remove the validation temporarily then you can put it back in later when you've tested the rest of the setup

Comment: Thank you so much.  The breakpoint helped here.  My validation is still broken and I'm not sure why, but the values are being sent to the Database. { CustomerID = 13, ProjectName = 1111 }.  Oddly, I couldn't tell you why this is working now.  I set breakpoints to see where this was getting to and well.. just kept continuing as it went and it's just working.  A result I'm not a fan of, because I can't give a complete answer to close this out.  Validation still needs to be looked at, but thank you for the breakpoint tip.  I'm going to learn more about them now.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if you get something that works in debug at a slow speed but not in production at full speed there could be some timing issue somewhere, like something not waiting long enough for another operation to complete. I don't think it's happening in this case but something to watch out for. Perhaps the validation is doing something odd and you'll get your answer when you work through it. Best of luck!